# How to open all Photo View instead of Album View in iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I am working on an iPhone app. I am opening gallery from my app grammatically, and its working fine, but currently albums are displaying, but I want all images to be display(not all albums). So can anybody help me to achieve this? or is it possible or not?

My code is:

```
UIAlertAction *Gallery = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Add Existing Photo" 
                                                  style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault 
                                                handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) 
{
    [alertcontroller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    // 
    self.multipleImagePicker = [[RPMultipleImagePickerViewController alloc] init];

    self.multipleImagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    // UIImagePickerController initialization

    self.picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage];

    // Photo Library
    self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:self.picker animated:YES completion:nil];

}];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `sourceType` as `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary`.

Please go through apple document. [UIImagePickerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/)

Comment: hello,kannan than you so much for quick ans.I am changing my code as per you guide,Please revert me once i've done,Thanks so much.

Comment: Please see my code,I have alrady given sourcetype as `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary`,But it opening albums view,Please help.

Comment: hello can you help me for the same issue for videos?